# How to freeze Parent Form while Child Form is open

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a situation where, in certain circumstances, i need to open another form and keep that form focused (modal = true) and when they are dont and it closes, a control on the parent form is refreshed with possible data that might have changed.

Originally i had a method that would `DoEvents` while the child form was open but it cause several of the child forms to be unusable (they werent databound at the form level) for data-entry/edits.

### ShowForm Method - Originally

```
Public Sub ShowForm(par As Form, nm As String, _
                    Optional whr As String = "", _
                    Optional args As String = "", _
                    Optional mode As AcFormOpenDataMode = acFormPropertySettings)
    DoCmd.OpenForm nm, acNormal, , whr, mode, , args
    
    While IsOpen(nm)
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

In order for me to get the Child Forms to be usable consistently, i had to comment out the `While...Wend` loop.

Is there another logic pattern i could use either inside this method or the OnClick of the calling control, so that way when they close the Child Form i could have code execute after the closing of the childform?

Comment: If you have opened the form modal, any code after the open code will not run until the form is closed. Note also that you can update the calling form from the open form.

Comment: ok so Popup + Modal True will provide a stationary pause in the calling event from parent form?

Comment: Open the form using the acdialog argument.

Comment: Can i have an Inheritance chain of Dialog Boxes?  Parent -> Child -> etc?

Comment: @GoldBishop: You'll have to maintain your own inheritance chain.  See my latest answer below for one approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final form of the method in my original question:  Works just as i wanted (for now ;) ), thanx to @Remou & @mwolfe02.

### Final Form - Tenative of course

```
'@frm - String value, Name of the form to Open
Public Sub OpenForm(frm As String, _
                    Optional vw As AcFormView = acNormal, _
                    Optional whr As String = "", _
                    Optional mode As AcFormOpenDataMode = acFormPropertySettings, _
                    Optional args As String = "")
    If FormExists(frm) Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm frm, vw, , whr, mode, acDialog, args
    Else
        RaiseError "Form ( " & frm & " ) does not exist!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                    "Alert your IT Support for further assistance."
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is to simply open the form in dialog mode.  For example,

```
DoCmd.OpenForm nm, acNormal, , whr, mode, acDialog, args
```

This will pause execution of the code in the calling module until the form is closed.  It will also prevent the user from interacting with any other forms until the "dialog" form is closed.

---

I have found that opening bound forms in dialog mode, updating the data, closing the form, then refreshing an object on the calling form (for example, a combo box's row source) is not always reliable.

What follows is a generic function that I've written to "pause" the calling code without opening the form in dialog mode and without noticeably affecting performance of the user interface.  It works for both forms and reports.  Note that the Sleep API declaration must go at the top of the code module (in the module declaration section).

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : WaitTilObjClosed
' Author    : Mike
' Date      : 1/7/2009
' Purpose   : Halts program execution until user closes object.  User is 
'               generally unaffected by the loop.
' Requires  : Sleep API sub
' Notes - while Sleeping other programs can use processor but access cannot;
'       - during DoEvents, other parts of Access can use processor;
'       - without the Sleep call, processor usage stays at 100% for MSACCESS.EXE
'       - with a long Sleep call, Access becomes noticeably sluggish
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Sub WaitTilObjClosed(ObjType As AcObjectType, ObjName As String)
    Do
        DoEvents
        Sleep 1
        If (SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, ObjType, ObjName) = 0) Then Exit Do
    Loop
End Sub
```

You would use it as follows:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm"
WaitTilObjClosed acForm, "MyForm"
MsgBox "MyForm is now closed"

DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewPreview
WaitTilObjClosed acReport, "MyReport"
MsgBox "MyReport is now closed"
```

Comment: Problem is that when the form is Popup - True & Modal - False, It freezes the child form to the point i can click on controls but selection  isnt made and almost seems like it its Unresponsive.  As you can see previously i had the `DoEvents` running in a loop similar to yours just used a different pattern for validation

Comment: I'll admit I've never tested this code with a form where Popup = True.  In cases where I want a form to behave as a popup I simply open it with the acDialog option: `DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", WindowMode:=acDialog`.  I use my WaitTilObjClosed code when I want to wait for the user to close a specific form, but still allow the user to navigate to other open forms (which is of course not possible in acDialog mode).  I assumed you were trying to do something similar here.

Comment: Nah, i want them to have access to the Application, just not the click heirarchy of open forms.  Parent -> Child -> GrandChild -> etc as they open other forms and then allow for eventual trickle-down closings back to the parent form.  Not worried about visible settings just want to "lock" the parent form while they have the child form open.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your issue now.  Unfortunately, there is no simple way to do what you want.  I would suggest the following algorithm:

```
'Grandparent/parent form module
Dim ChildForm As String

Private Sub ShowFormBtn_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm"
    ChildForm = "MyForm"
End Sub    

Private Sub ShowOtherFormBtn_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "OtherForm"
    ChildForm = "OtherForm"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Activate()
    On Error Resume Next
    Forms(ChildForm).SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    On Error Resume Next
    Forms(ChildForm).SetFocus
    If Err.Number = 0 Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Basically, each time you try to switch to a parent form it will try to send the user to its child form (if one exists).  If it has no child, there is an error generated that is silently ignored.  If the child does exist, it switches it to that form.

This supports multiple levels as well.  So say you have a grandparent form that spawns a parent form that spawns a child form.  All three forms are open.  You click on the Grandparent form which sends focus to the Parent form which sends focus on to the Child form.

Comment: Posted this as a separate answer because my original answer is more general (and consequently will be more helpful to future visitors who find this question via Google) while this one more directly deals with your specific case.

Comment: `DoCmd.OpenForm nm, acNormal, , whr, mode, acDialog, args` worked just fine....it applied the inheritence chain that i need.  I have multiple forms that have the possibility of opening each other but at no point will any of the "child" forms open a form that is already open, so i dont have to worry about the situation where a "child" form is already open and is the child to a different form.  IE none of the "out" branches will ever route backwards down a different branch and will always be one-way parent-child associations.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to lock the `FORM` itself, you want to lock the controls that are a part of the `FORM`.  Below explains my preferred method for doing control lock-downs.  The goal is to make every user-editable control read-only

in the VBA code for your parent `FORM` create this sub:

```
public sub LockControls_[Enter Form Name Here]()

  ME.txt1.Locked = True
  ME.txt2.Locked = True
  ME.txt3.Locked = True
...

end sub
```

You can lock down Text Boxes, Combo Boxes, Buttons, etc...

If your controls follow a naming structure like I outlined above, you can actually loop this by doing the following:

```
public sub LockControls_[Enter Form Name Here]()

  Dim s_ctrl As String
  Dim s_obj As String
  Dim i as Int

  i = 0
  s_ctrl = "txt"
  s_obj = s_ctrl & i

  do while me(s_obj).Name <> ""

      Me(s_obj).Locked = True
      i = i+1
      s_obj = s_ctrl & i

  loop
end sub
```

Call this method from the action which launches your child form.  It will lock down (make read only) all controls on the form, while leaving the form accessible to the user.

This same method can be used to unlock your parent `FORM` when called from the closing event on the child form.  Just be sure to NOT use `Me(s_obj).Locked = False`.  Instead, fully qualify your form by using the syntax:

```
public sub UnLockControls_[Enter Parent Form Name Here]()

  Dim s_ctrl As String
  Dim s_obj As String
  Dim i as Int

  i = 0
  s_ctrl = "txt"
  s_obj = s_ctrl & i

  do while me(s_obj).Name <> ""

      FORMS![form_name](s_obj).Locked = False
      i = i+1
      s_obj = s_ctrl & i

  loop
end sub
```