# VBA Wait until form open

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have the following VBA in an Access project:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Importing"
' Some CPU-intensive code
```

The problem is, I just get a white screen until the intensive part is done.

How can I wait until the form is open before executing the rest of the code?

Comment: here is an old post of mine....might get youw hat you want [StackOverflow - How to freeze parent form while child form is open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305387/how-to-freeze-parent-form-while-child-form-is-open)

Comment: @GoldBishop Thanks for the post, but that's not actually what I'm looking for. Your accepted answer pauses the parent form until the child form is closed. For me, I needed the parent form to just pause until the child form is *loaded*. Reason being, this is contained within a Button Click on the Main Menu, which calls a form called Importing, and regularly updates it with information. The Importing form itself doesn't have any textboxes (only labels), so isn't bound to any data. Thanks though!

Comment: Depending on your need and library accessibility the answers below will work but you could morph the solution i needed to fit yours.  You may also want to look at the Form property `Data-Wati for Post Processing' as an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for the question guys, I've just found the answer (one of them cases of Googling for a while, posting to SO, and finding the answer right after):

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Importing"
DoEvents
' Some CPU-intensive code
```

Comment: After changing label captions (etc) on the Importing form from the Main Menu, `DoEvents` will also immediately update them labels.

Comment: +1 Yep do events is there to allow the processing to catch up, in some cases, especially when running multiple sets of intensive code, I like to reference the "Sleep" API also with my doevents and make it pause for say a tenth of a second.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness sake, you could also use the following function I can't remember where I got it from, but I didn't write it:

```
Function IsLoaded(ByVal strFormName As String) As Boolean
' Returns True if the specified form is open in Form view or Datasheet view.
' Use form name according to Access, not VBA.
' Only works for Access
    Dim oAccessObject As AccessObject

    Set oAccessObject = CurrentProject.AllForms(strFormName)
    If oAccessObject.IsLoaded Then
        If oAccessObject.CurrentView <> acCurViewDesign Then
            IsLoaded = True
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Then in your code:

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "Importing"
    Do While Not ISLoaded("Importing")
        DoEvents
    Loop
```