# NotInList Message Box

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

In my database I have three related tables; tblG5Property, tblG3ZIP, tblG2City. tblG5Property has a fk linked to pk in tblG3ZIP which has a fk linked to pk in tblG2City.

I have two forms related to these tables, frmProperty & frmCity. When the user adds a new address and needs to add a new ZIP Code, I have the following code in the NotInList even for the ctrlg5ZIP combobox in the frmProperty.

```
Private Sub ctrlg5ZIP_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
On Error GoTo ctrlg5ZIP_NotInList_Err

'Variable Declarations
Dim vntResult
Dim dbsCurrent As Database
Dim rstZIPs As Recordset

' Exit this subroutine if the combo box was cleared.
If NewData = "" Then Exit Sub

If MsgBox("The City/ZIP " & NewData & " is not currently listed." _
    & vbCrLf & "Would you like to add it to the list now?", vbQuestion + vbOKCancel, _
    "Homeland Real Estate") = vbOK Then

    Response = acDataErrAdded
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCity", , , , acFormAdd, acNormal

Else
    'Return User to form
    Response = acDataErrContinue
    MsgBox "Please try again!", , "Homeland Real Estate"
    Me!ctrlg2City.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

'Error Handling
ctrlg5ZIP_NotInList_Exit:
    Exit Sub

ctrlg5ZIP_NotInList_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume ctrlg5ZIP_NotInList_Exit

End Sub
```

My problem is that the error message "The text you entered isn't an item in the list" pops up immediately. I've added the next code to my frmCity AfterUpdate event but the error pops up as soon as the frmCity opens, not after it closes.

```
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
'From http://allenbrowne.com/ser-27.html#NotInList
'Purpose:   Requery the combo that may have called this in its DblClick
Dim cbo As ComboBox
Dim iErrCount As Integer
Const strcCallingForm = "frmProperty"

If CurrentProject.AllForms(strcCallingForm).IsLoaded Then
    Set cbo = Forms(strcCallingForm)!ctrlg5ZIP
    cbo.Requery
End If

Exit_Handler:
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    'Undo the combo if it has a partially entered value.
    If (Err.Number = 2118) And (iErrCount < 3) And Not (cbo Is Nothing) Then
        cbo.Undo
        Resume
    End If
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
Resume Exit_Handler
```

I need to find a way to prevent the error from popping up until AFTER the frmCity is updated and closed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about debugging your code or at displaying the value of NewData?

Comment: The code includes a message box that uses the NewData so I know it is capturing that portion of it. The code works as needed up to the form opening. The problem is that it continues after the form is open and requeries the control even though the City form hasn't been updated yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was finally able to find a way to do what I've been trying for. I found most of my answer at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305777/2360108 That post gives a sub for pausing code until the subform is closed. But then I ran into another problem.

I wasn't allowing the frmCity to populate with new PKs for City & ZIP. I had to use the OpenArgs to fix that problem.

I've added the following to my frmProperty NotInList code

```
   Dim NewZIP As String
        'Create New ZIP ID
    NewZIP = (DMax("g3ID", "[tblG3ZIP]") + 1) & "|" & (DMax("g2ID", "[tblG2City]") + 1)

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCity", , , , acFormAdd, acNormal, NewZIP
    WaitTilObjClosed acForm, "frmCity"
    Response = acDataErrAdded
```

I've added this to the frmCity OnOpen event

```
'Script for Opening the form as a subform to add new City & ZIP
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim NewIDs
On Error GoTo Err_Form_Open

If IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then Exit Sub

'Load new ZIP ID from Property form
NewIDs = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")
Me!ctrlg3ID.DefaultValue = NewIDs(0)
Me!ctrlg2ID.DefaultValue = NewIDs(1)

Exit_Form_Open:
    Exit Sub

Err_Form_Open:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Form_Open

End Sub
```

I've tested the forms and they works just fine.